# Is there a way to set a maximum timeout in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sql-server

can anyone help me with this?
there is 31,000 rows of data from **trial_exporthinban** and only 3000 rows from **Cabinet_Data_Hinban** and I got an error like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8IzN.png)
but I tried to reduce data from **trial_exporthinban** into 1000 only and it works.
so I think the problem here is node timeout but I dont know how to fix it.

by the way I am using mysql for the **trial_exporthinban** table and sql server for the **Cabinet_Data_Hinban**

```
router.get('/unregisterHinban', (req, res) => {
  knex.select('ExportHinban').from('trial_exporthinban')
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data.length, 'data')
      if(data.length > 0) {
        let a = data.map(rec => {
          return "'" + rec.ExportHinban + "'"
        })
        var s = a.toString()
        var stmt ="select DISTINCT (HINBAN +'-'+ CLR) as hinban from Cabinet_Data_Hinban " +
         "where HINBAN +'-'+ CLR not in ("+ a.toString() + ") " +
         "and hinban like 'S%' " +
         "and BarchartNo = 2"
        // console.log(stmt)
        knex1.raw(stmt)
        .then(data => {
            let b = data.map(rec => {
              var str = rec.hinban.split('').reverse().join('')
              var clr = str.split('-')
              var name = ""
              for(let a=0; a<=rec.hinban.split("-").length-2; a++){
                name = name + rec.hinban.split("-")[a] + "-"
                // console.log(name)
              }
              name = name.substr(0, name.length-1)
              return {
                hinban: rec.hinban,
                name: name,
                color: clr[0].split('').reverse().join('')
              } 
            })
            res.status(200).send(b)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error, '2')
          res.sendStatus(404)
        })
      } else {
        res.send(data)
        console.log('else')
      }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error, '1')
    res.sendStatus(404)
  })
})
```

Comment: look at the server timeouts 150000 culd result there

Comment: @nbk, you mean to connection string?

Comment: Connection strings can only control connection timeouts. Sounds like you want to control the query timeouts - how long a query can run for after a connection is established. Have you tried using the [timeout()](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-timeout) method?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes I've tried it already, I got the same error

Comment: no mysql has more timeouts 3 timeouts for session, with mysql workbench and preferences you see them all

Comment: You should consider evaluating your schema and indexes and make the query run faster; 3000 rows out of 30000 should not exceed your query timeout.